# Windows Live Mesh and hard disk reinstall

Tags: windows

I use Windows Live Mesh to sync some folders to SkyDrive synced storage. I am wondering what would happen if my hard disk crashed and I had to reinstall Windows.

After reinstalling Windows & Live Mesh would it think I had deleted my folders and therefore delete the folders on the SkyDrive synced storage as well? Or would it be clever enough to reinstate the folders/files from SkyDrive synced storage?

If when reinstalling I gave the computer a different name then before I reckon there would be no problems, but what if I gave it the same name?

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 0):

You know, I have no idea.  I can't find any documentation on it.  I would presume/hope that each install of Live Mesh creates a unique identifier for the service separate from the machine name, but that may be wishful thinking.

That being said, you can manually Stop Syncing for a folder in Live Mesh, download the files you want to the new PC from SkyDrive, then turn Syncing back on, which would endrun the problem rather nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you actually download the files from SkyDrive? The SkyDrive synced storage seems to have no options to manipulate the files at all. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You can download them, though it's not a wonderful interface.  You have to browse to the file in question and hit download.